# Auditing and reporting config file changes across servers

Tags: open-source, file-synchronization

Is there any open source tool that can help me to maintain consistency of files across nodes?

Suppose there is one master file on the master node (nginx.conf). I'm looking for a tool that compares the file with the client servers and if there are any changes in the file on any of client, report back.

Comment: Any suggestions where please